# How to duplicate HTML code using handlebars or other method

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I am trying to create 3 cards using the exact same html for each one. I have implemented handlebars to get the content from contentful. Everything works as it should, but I have the exact same code written 3 times in the html. Is there a way to make it so I only write the html once, and handlebars duplicates the content 2 other times without me having to re-write the same code? here is a template of what I am doing:

```
 <script id="template-press-category" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each categories}}
          <hr class="divider" />
          <h2 class="section-title">{{this.fields.name}}</h2>
          <div class="press-section">
            {{#ifGt this.fields.pressReleases.length 0}}
            
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-image" src="{{cdn img}}" class="card-image" />
              <a href="{{link}}" download>
                {{#each this.fields.pressReleases}}
                <img
                  src="{{this.fields.gridImage.fields.file.url}}"
                  alt="Shelfology-wall"
                />
                <div class="card-text">
                  <p class="card-title">{{this.fields.name}}</p>
                  <span class="download-link">DOWNLOAD</span>
                </div>
                {{/each}}
              </a>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-image" src="{{cdn img}}" class="card-image" />
              <a href="{{link}}" download>
                {{#each this.fields.pressReleases}}
                <img
                  src="{{this.fields.gridImage.fields.file.url}}"
                  alt="Shelfology-wall"
                />
                <div class="card-text">
                  <p class="card-title">{{this.fields.name}}</p>
                  <span class="download-link">DOWNLOAD</span>
                </div>
                {{/each}}
              </a>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-image" src="{{cdn img}}" class="card-image" />
              <a href="{{link}}" download>
                {{#each this.fields.pressReleases}}
                <img
                  src="{{this.fields.gridImage.fields.file.url}}"
                  alt="Shelfology-wall"
                />
                <div class="card-text">
                  <p class="card-title">{{this.fields.name}}</p>
                  <span class="download-link">DOWNLOAD</span>
                </div>
                {{/each}}
              </a>
            </div>

            {{/ifGt}}
          </div>
        {{/each}}

      </script>
```

maybe something like {{#each duplicate x3}} or something like that.

Comment: Did you have a look at the `<template>` html element? It allows you to write HTML without it being rendered. You can then manipulate it with Javascript and render it as many times as you want. No need to use a library for this. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Comment: You would use an `#each`, like `{{#each duplicates}}`. This assumes an Array named "duplicates" in which each object would represent a card to be duplicated.